# How can I get the log filename through code?

Tags: c#, log4net, app-config

How can I get the log filename in code? (So I can print it to the console)

My log file is define like this in app.config:

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender"
   type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logfile" />
    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You look at your [LogManager.GetAllRepositories](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.LogManager.GetAllRepositories.html). Inside the repositories you look at all the appenders in [ILoggerRepository.GetAppenders](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository.GetAppenders.html). If the appender is of type [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html) you check its [File](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.File.html) property, or if you preffer you can check the appender by [Name](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.IAppender.Name.html).

That being said it is *very* bad to do something like this in your code. What if the configuration is changed at deployment and the appender you expect is no longer present?

Comment: Well, I can check for null values.  What about reading the app.config somehow?

Comment: see the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.getsection.aspx on how to read your own config section(s). I'd recommend againts it, though.

Comment: I'd like to print out to the console where the log file is for convenience.  Any way to do this you would suggest?

Comment: My point is that log4net allow for *any* appender. If is a file appender is fine, you can search the LogManager and display the File property, as in my post. But what if is an appender *you have no idea exists*, eg. the appender my company provides at http://bugcollect.com/downloads ? Anyone can add such and appender to your application.config and remove your RollingFileAppender, so what are you going to print then?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume that, *if* someone would make such a change, testing would occur and the broken code depending on a `RollingFileAppender` would be fixed/removed. Saying that *anyone* can add and remove appenders, is not correct. All in all unreasonable fear, imho.

Answer (score 0):

see File property of this.

Log is ILog's instance

((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.DefaultLoggerFactory.LoggerImpl)Log.Logger).Appenders.OfType().FirstOrDefault().File